# How to use Google Sheets IMPORTXML function to get Sector and Industry values from Fidelity website

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I am trying to use the IMPORTXML function in Google Sheets to retrieve the "Sector" and "Industry" values under "Company Profile" for Fidelity's website here:

https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/research/quote/dashboard/summary?symbol=AAPL

My cell formula is:

```
=importxml("https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/research/quote/dashboard/summary?symbol=AAPL","div[@class='company-profile-body']")
```

...but even that is returning #N/A error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It fails because it uses JavaScript. I have found an alternate solution.